# Multiple email receivers in prometheus alertmanager "to" field

Tags: email, configuration, monitoring, prometheus

How can I create a receiver configuration with multiple email addresses in the "to" field?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can put comma separated email addresses in the `to` field.

`to: 'user1@example.com, user2@example.com'`

Comment: Im trying this but its not working
receivers:
  - name: 'team-one-mails'
    email_configs:
    - to: 'bla1@bla.com', 'bla2@bla.com'
      from: 'prometheus@bla.com'
      require_tls: false
      send_resolved: true

Comment: @Shell_Leko instead of to: 'bla1@bla.com', 'bla2@bla.com'. Try the comma in the single quotes, so 'bla1@bla.com, bla2@bla.com'. This way the two emails will be passed as one string comma separated.

Comment: That did not work for me. Only thing the work was using two "to" configurations.

Answer (score 12):

For prometheus 1.8 I am using two "to" configurations in the same receiver.

```
receivers:

  - name: 'bla1-and-bla2-mails'
    email_configs:
    - to: 'bla1@example.com' 
      from: 'prometheus@example.com'
      require_tls: false
      send_resolved: true
    - to: 'bla2@example.com'
      from: 'prometheus@example.com'
      require_tls: false
      send_resolved: true
```